# autostart chromium fullscreen NOT kiosk

Tags: noobs

I want chromium to start up fullscreen with the default startup pages but I don't want it to start in kiosk mode.  I've tried a desktop entry and running it from ...LXDE-pi autostart by just leaving the -kiosk out of the command but it does not work.

I have the Noobs 2.8.1 installed on the raspberry pi.

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your LXDE-pi `chromium-browser --start-fullscreen`. To Exit later just press F11 and it's back to windowed mode.